# How do we differentiate the below equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logarithms

The question is to differentiate the equation in the image:
[image: Question]

$$f(x)=x^x+e^{x-x^3}-\ln(\ln(3x))$$

Comment: With copious application of the chain rule. I would figure out the derivative of the first one separately, as you need a trick beyond just the ordinary chain rule for that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of the chain rule. Nothing should be too difficult, except maybe $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^x)$, which I will just give to you, it is equal to $x^x(\ln(x)+1)$. There are many tutorials online which show you how to get this and on MSE too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oPJzxmFS0k

Then it's easy.

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{x-x^3})=e^{x-x_3}\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-x^3)=e^{x-x^3}(1-3x^2)$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(-\ln(\ln(3x))=\dfrac{-1}{\ln(3x)}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln(3x))=\dfrac{-1}{\ln(3x)}\dfrac{1}{3x}*3=\dfrac{-1}{x\ln(3x)}$

Then your derivaitve is just the sum of all of these, which becomes:

$$x^x(\ln(x)+1)+e^{x-x^3}(1-3x^2)-\dfrac{1}{x\ln(3x)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @K Split X